# Remove parameters in the url in the Laravel controller

Tags: php, url, laravel-5

I am currently working with an existing project that is for maintenance. So per testing, there's a scenario that is having an error

> Request-URI Too Large
>
> The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

This is error happens because our clients uses the `GET` method, and I don't wanna change their settings since there are other complex logic that might be affected. So I tried the approach to change the URL using javascript but still the same error. Now what I'm thinking, is it possible for us to change the URL in the controller? Like use the url current path:

```
url()->current();
```

rather than the fullpath ?

```
url()->full();
```

I badly need your help on this one, I'm stuck on this part for days already.

Answer (score 0):

Under Apache, the limit is a configurable value, [`LimitRequestLine`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline). Change this value to something larger than its default of 8190 if you want to support a longer request URI. The value is in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. If not, add a new line (`LimitRequestLine 10000`) under `AccessFileName .htaccess`.

However, note that if you're actually running into this limit, you are probably abusing `GET` to begin with. You should use `POST` to transmit this sort of data -- especially since you even concede that you're using it to update values. If you check the link above, you'll notice that Apache even says "Under normal conditions, the value should not be changed from the default."

Comment: Thanks for this one but for now, I'm trying other ways to surpass this. This might be my last resort

Comment: I'm using httpd, where can I possibly locate this one?